# mysqli_real_escape_string Not working inside array_map

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, array-map

I have a function to making a insert query, But if i use `mysqli_real_escape_string` its not response with the values. This is the problem inside the array map so i can't figure out how to solve this.

> Server version: 5.6.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

**My function is:**

```
function insertQryStr($array, $table){
    $insertUrl = "insert into %s(%s) values('%s')";
    $insertQryStr = sprintf($insertUrl, $table, implode(', ',@array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', @array_keys($array))), implode("', '",  @array_map('mysql_escape_string', $array)));
    return $insertQryStr;
}
```

Comment: What does _its not response with the values._ means???

Comment: You've put `@` at the beginning of the functions. That's the error suppression operator. Take that off and it'll tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: Use `mysqli_` functions rather than `mysql_escape_string` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, if i use `mysqli_real_escape_string` then the query looks like : _insert into table_name(, , , , , , ) values('', '', '', '', '', '', '')_

Comment: @castis, If i do that than some warning comes out.

Comment: What is the warning you receive?

Comment: @wogsland, I am asking about that why i can't use `mysqli_*`...

Comment: @castis, `Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given ...............`

Comment: Just stop. Please, you're out of control here. Read the documentation on [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) before just trying things randomly. Manual escaping is extremely error prone and strongly discouraged.

Comment: the mysql_ has been removed in php 7.0.0 http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php and escaping will not protect from sql injection http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @JasonK Technically escaping *is* to protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_real\_escape\_string and array\_map returns blank strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625737/mysql-real-escape-string-and-array-map-returns-blank-strings)

Comment: The call to `array_map` is failing because `mysqli_real_escape_string` when used as a function requires 2 arguments, the first being `mysqli $link` [as per the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @castis, How can i use the `array_walk` in my function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `array_map` is failing because `mysqli_real_escape_string` when used as a function requires 2 arguments, the first being `mysqli $link` [as per the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

`array_map` doesn't know to pass a connection as the first argument. A better method would be from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625737/mysql-real-escape-string-and-array-map-returns-blank-strings).

To use this with your function, you'll need to pass in a link to the database.

```
function insertQryStr($array, $table, $link) {
    array_walk($array, function(&$string) use ($link) { 
        $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $string);
    });

    return sprintf("insert into %s (%s) values('%s')",
        $table,
        implode(", ", array_keys($array)),
        implode("', '", $array)
    );
}
```

Although a better idea would be to do this **before** calling `insertQryStr()` as to avoid [tight coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832017/what-is-the-difference-between-loose-coupling-and-tight-coupling-in-object-orien).

Having said all that, instead of manually escaping data this way, you should check out and definitely use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: How can i use the `array_walk` in my function??

Comment: MySQL 7 isn't a thing. PHP 7 is, and I don't know whether or not it will.