# MYSQL real escape string observation

Tags: php, mysql

I have some strange observation with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

when trying this code on a localhost WAMP server, I am getting:

```
mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

The code is like this:

```
$_POST= array (
  'level_id' => '4',
  'initLevel' => '4',
  'subject_ids' => 
  array (
    0 => '6',
  ),
  'category' => '11',
  'areas' => '-1',
  'dist_code' => '',
  'district' => '',
  'gender_preference' => '2',
  'race' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
  'with_photo' => '0',
  'min_age' => '',
  'max_age' => '',
  'notification' => '1',
  'ban_tutor' => '',
  'sort_by' => 'regi_date',
  'fromdate' => '',
  'day' => '14',
  'month' => '5',
  'year' => '2017',
  'todate' => '2017-06-14',
  'result_page' => '10',
  'search' => 'Search Tutors',
);

$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
echo '<pre>' . var_export($_GET, true) . '</pre>';exit;
```

but when I am trying the same on the live server.
I am not getting any error, but the result is stripped the array values like this:

```
array (
  'level_id' => '4',
  'initLevel' => '4',
  'subject_ids' => NULL,
  'category' => '11',
  'dist_code' => '',
  'district' => '',
  'gender_preference' => '2',
  'race' => NULL,
  'with_photo' => '0',
  'min_age' => '',
  'max_age' => '',
  'notification' => '1',
  'ban_tutor' => '',
  'sort_by' => 'regi_date',
  'fromdate' => '',
  'day' => '14',
  'month' => '5',
  'year' => '2017',
  'todate' => '2017-06-14',
  'result_page' => '10',
  'search' => 'Search Tutors',
)
```

Need some direction, how to use it correctly.

Note: I know `mysql_real_escape-string` is deprecated and PDO is the the appropriate solution. I am just working on my client's server. The changing the complete system immediately is not feasible.

Comment: What version of PHP is on the live site and what version are you using on your local test site?

Comment: on live site - 5.6.30 and localhost 5.6.25

Comment: what is the api used to connect with, `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other? and where's the HTML for this? @Pawan

Comment: there's also not enough code to support your question. Either you edit your post, or ping me back or take it up with the answer given below. If you don't like waiting for a solution, neither do I so put yourself in my shoes and walk that mile for a while ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Least "you" got an answer [as did the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543766/1415724).

Comment: Even that would still be too good for 'em @RiggsFolly and basically doing "their" homework. Nah, I'll pass. He can take it up with the answer below. Not my idea of "playing ball" at all. I just voted as the generic close.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what is the api used - it is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use my_sqli instead of mysql.

**Now,**

we can do something like this :

```
$escaped_row = array_map(array($link, 'mysqli_real_escape_string');
```

But `array_map` doesn't know to pass a connection as the first argument.

So my opinion is use array walk.

```
array_walk($_POST, function(&$string) use ($link) { 
  $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $string);
});
```

**Note:** $link is your valid connection.

[mysql_real_escape_string and array_map returns blank strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625737/mysql-real-escape-string-and-array-map-returns-blank-strings)

Comment: you're guessing as to which api is used to connect with. Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44543766/1

Comment: you also missed the 4th argument on the connection. Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44543766/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- now is okey or need to improve?

Comment: sure, wait for the OP, I have counted myself out of the question.

Comment: @AhmedGinani - `Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'mysqli' does not have a method 'mysqli_real_escape_string'`

Comment: @AhmedGinani - Ok your answer is correct. only you need to modify it `array_walk_recursive` and it works like a charm.